# Передача значения input в php скрипт используя ajax

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

сделал таблицу используя datatable, хочу сделать поиск для каждого столбца, но не знаю, как передавать данные из полей типа input в мой php скрипт. Подскажите плс.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html >
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Language" content="ru">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="DataTables/datatables.min.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="DataTables/datatables.min.js"></script>

    
</head>
<body>
<table id='empTable' class='display dataTable'>

  <thead>
    <tr>
            <td><input placeholder="" name='s_DocumentName' id='s_DocumentName' /></td>
            <td><input placeholder="" name='s_DocumentNumber' id='s_DocumentNumber' /></td>
            <td><input placeholder="" name='s_DocumnetFormat' id='s_DocumnetFormat' /></td>
            <td><input placeholder="" name='s_OriginalInventoryNumber' id='s_OriginalInventoryNumber' /></td>
            <td><input placeholder="" name='s_OriginalDataSupplay' id='s_OriginalDataSupplay' /></td>
            <td><input placeholder="" name='s_DuplicationInventoryNumber' id='s_DuplicationInventoryNumber' /></td>
            <td><input placeholder="" name='s_DuplicationDataSupplay' id='s_DuplicationDataSupplay' /></td>
            <td><input placeholder="" name='s_DesignationApplicability' id='s_DesignationApplicability' /></td>
            <td><input placeholder="" name='s_CypherApplicability' id='s_CypherApplicability' /></td>
            <td><input placeholder="" name='s_ForMarks' id='s_ForMarks' /></td>
            <td><input placeholder="" name='s_Letter' id='s_Letter' /></td>
        </tr>
        

    <tr>
        <th><b>Наименование</b></th>
        <th><b>Номер документа</b></th>
        <th><b>Формат</b></th>
        <th><b>Подлинник<br>Инвентарный номер</b></th>
        <th><b>Подлинник<br>Дата поступления</b></th>
        <th><b>Дубликат<br>Инвентарный номер</b></th>
        <th><b>Дубликат<br>Дата поступления</b></th>
        <th><b>Применяемость<br>Обозначение</b></th>
        <th><b>Применяемость<br>Шифр индекса изделия</b></th>
        <th><b>Для отметок</b></th>
        <th><b>Литера</b></th>
    </tr>
    </thead>

</table>
</body>
</html>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('#empTable').DataTable({
  'processing': true,
  'serverSide': true,
  "lengthMenu": [[10, 25, 50, 1000000000], [10, 25, 50, "All"]],
  "pageLength": 25,
    dom: 'lfBrtip',
    buttons: [
        'excelHtml5'
    ],
    language: {
                  "processing": "Подождите...",
                  "search": "Поиск:",
                  "lengthMenu": "Показать _MENU_ записей",
                  "info": "Записи с _START_ до _END_ из _TOTAL_ записей",
                  "infoEmpty": "Записи с 0 до 0 из 0 записей",
                  "infoFiltered": "(отфильтровано из _MAX_ записей)",
                  "infoPostFix": "",
                  "loadingRecords": "Загрузка записей...",
                  "zeroRecords": "Записи отсутствуют.",
                  "emptyTable": "В таблице отсутствуют данные",
                  "paginate": {
                    "first": "Первая",
                    "previous": "Предыдущая",
                    "next": "Следующая",
                    "last": "Последняя"
                  },
                  "aria": {
                    "sortAscending": ": активировать для сортировки столбца по возрастанию",
                    "sortDescending": ": активировать для сортировки столбца по убыванию"
                  },
                  "select": {
                    "rows": {
                      "_": "Выбрано записей: %d",
                      "0": "Кликните по записи для выбора",
                      "1": "Выбрана одна запись"
                    }
                  }
                },
  'serverMethod': 'post',
  'ajax': {
      'url':'back_2.php'
  },
  'columns': [
    
     { data: 'DocumentName' },
     { data: 'DocumentNumber' },
     { data: 'DocumnetFormat' },
     { data: 'OriginalInventoryNumber' },
     { data: 'OriginalDataSupplay' },
     { data: 'DuplicationInventoryNumber' },
     { data: 'DuplicationDataSupplay' },
     { data: 'DesignationApplicability' },
     { data: 'CypherApplicability' },
     { data: 'ForMarks' },
     { data: 'Letter' },
  ],
 
  
      });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: `'url':'back_2.php?field1=Text&field2=Text'`?

Comment: @u_mulder а как вместо текст вписать данные из input'а, я пытался через $('#s_DocumentName').val(); но не выходит

Comment: `'url':'back_2.php?field1=' + $('#id1').val() + '&field2=' + $('#id2').val()`

Comment: @u_mulder что-то я не подумал, что мне нужно, чтобы при вводе данных в input помимо передачи данных, вызывался мой php скрипт при помощи ajax и данные в отображаемой таблице фильтровались

Comment: @u_mulder я смог добавить функцию в ajax: 'ajax': {
   'url':'back_2.php',
   data : function ( d ){
    d.custom = $('#s_DocumentName').val();
   
    },

Comment: @u_mulder  но не могу сделать, чтобы происходила отправка данных при непосредственном вводе данных в поле

Comment: @u_mulder вот, чем я руководствовался https://datatables.net/examples/server_side/custom_vars.html

Answer (score 0):

```
dataTableParams.ajax.data = function(p) {
    p.postvar = $('input[name=email]').val();
};
```

Вот пример из предыдущего проекта, дальше додумать не сложно.

Answer (score 0):

Не стоит усложнять. Вы можете все значения input передать с помощью метода serialize().

```
$.ajax({
    data: $("").serialize(),
    ...остальное
});
```